PowerShell to RegEx Find and Replace MS Word
Every week, I have a system generated document that needs serious reformatting to be usable. Unfortunately, with no control over the generation system, I'm trying to make a PowerShell script automate my formatting actions.
Input: The document is generated as plain text that is usually copied by the user into a Word file, though NotePad is also an option.
The Problem: The reformatting is complicated and I need full Regular Expressions to properly find and fix the various formatting issues. MS Word's implementation of RegEx is insufficient. However, I can't find a good way to RegEx search and replace text in MS Word documents without using the MS Word Find and Replace function.
End Goal: A formatted docx file with correct headers, footers, page numbers, and data.
Example RegEx:
/(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(AM|PM) (\d{4})/i

The above RegEx is probably the simplest, as I need to:

Find the date on every page
Save it to a variable
Delete it from every page
Add it to the First Page header and the Primary Header

Specifically, MS Word does not support the RegEx OR operator, which is a key problem. I have a lot of OR searches that I need to make.
Possible solutions?

Copy the document into NotePad, do RegEx modifications, convert to Docx, then format/set headers and footers.
Pull the text stream into a PowerShell variable(s), parse and modify it directly, then put it back into the Document.

(My apologies for any weird wording. I'm running on 5 hours of sleep...)
